# Android, Espresso. Is it possible and is it good to call one test method from another?

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my android project I have 2 test classes in a folder:

*app\src\androidTest\java\com\mycompany\fragment*

- Fragment1Test
- Fragment2Test

In class **Fragment1Test** I have 1 Espresso test method "**testShowTitle**".

In class **Fragment2Test** I have 1 test Espresso method "**testSwipeEffect**".

And all works fine. OK.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to call the test method **testSwipeEffect** from another test class (**Fragment1Test**).?
2. Is it a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could call it but it is not considered a good practice where one test method calls another test method. If there is some shared functionality between the 2 tests, i would recommend to add it to another class and call that method in both the tests.